# I wanna convert this sorted loop to a regular loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I wanna convert this to a regular for loop

```
for i in sorted(pdict.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True):
            if(i[1]<rating):
                print("Jersey number: "+str(i[0])+", Rating: "+str(i[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean like this?

```
for i in pdict.items():
    if(i[1]<rating):
        print("Jersey number: "+str(i[0])+", Rating: "+str(i[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

> convert this to a regular for loop

Ok, here you go.

```
for i in pdict.items():
    if i[1] < rating:
        print("Jersey number: " + str(i[0]) + ", Rating: " + str(i[1]))
```

But perhaps you wanted to clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can also make `i` more explicitly defined by specifying that two values are coming from `.items()`: the dictionary key and the dictionary value. The syntax below makes that more clear.

```
for key, value in pdict.items():
    if value < rating:
        print(f"Jersey number: {key}, Rating: {value}")
```